# Connect UITableView to Firebase results

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview, firebase

Does anyone have any experience with Firebase? I am trying to make information I have within firebase show up within a navigation controller. Whenever I run the program the information shows that it is being received because I have print lines printing whatever it receives to the command prompt however an error is thrown.

```
NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier CellIdentifier - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard
```

My swift file is here:

```
//
//  All.swift
//  Guaranteed Pricing
//
//  Created by DePauw on 3/30/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 DePauw. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import UIKit
import Firebase

class All: UINavigationController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var items: [String] = []
    var tableView: UITableView!
    let cellIdentifier = "CellIdentifier"

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView = UITableView(frame:self.view!.frame)
        self.tableView!.delegate = self
        self.tableView!.dataSource = self
        self.tableView!.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        self.view?.addSubview(self.tableView)

        let ref = Firebase(url:"https://<firebase-id>.firebaseio.com/services")
        ref.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
            // do some stuff once
            print(snapshot.value)

            // get these values and put them in the cell's text view. key is more important
            print(snapshot.key)

            // add to the array and just this array
            self.items.append(snapshot.key)

            self.tableView!.reloadData()
        })
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)

        // Fetch Fruit
        let fruit = items[indexPath.row]

        // Configure Cell
        cell.textLabel?.text = fruit
        return cell
    }

    // onclick printing
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        print(items[indexPath.row])
    }
}
```

I want to download all of the information found in:

```
let ref = Firebase(url:"https://<firebase-id>.firebaseio.com/services")
            ref.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
                // do some stuff once
                print(snapshot.value)

                // get these values and put them in the cell's text view. key is more important
                print(snapshot.key)

                // add to the array and just this array
                self.items.append(snapshot.key)

                self.tableView!.reloadData()
            })
```

Without throwing an error. This is my storyboard:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You registered your cell with the wrong identifier. Change that line to:

```
self.tableView!.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
```

Answer (score 0):

That Firebase code is going to cause you trouble.

When observing by .Value, remember that everything within that node is returned; all children, children of children etc. You are going to want to iterate over the children returned to get the key:value pairs

You didn't post your structure but assume this with the keys generated with childByAutoId

```
services
   -Jikaijsipaij
     service_name: "my service"
   -kalksdokoas
     service_name: "another service"
```

.value returns everything within services so iterating over the children will retrieve each key and child value of that key.

```
ref.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

    for child in snapshot.children {

        let key = child.key as NSString //returns -Jikaijsipaij and -kalksdokoas
        let name = child.value.objectForKey("service_name") as! NSString

        self.items.append(key)
    }
})
```

Comment: I keep getting a "value of object is unwrapped" for the value and key whenever I use your code Jay. It makes sense to me but for some reason x code is having trouble reading the variables key and name. I even tried to declare local variables showing them as strings.

Comment: @AdrianAbles My apologies - forgot to define what child.key was:  updated the answer with 'as NSString'. Don't forget that the data structure MUST contain service_name as defined above.

Comment: no pronlem Jay! I really appreciate your help. I just changed the NSString, cleaned the project, and changed the data structure but the same errors are still occurring. Also there is an error that occurs right before value that keeps happening and I am not sure why. The error keeps trying to place a '?' or '!' after value.

Comment: @AdrianAbles Hmm, I would say the error is happening outside of the code above. I just created a new project, entered the firebase structure shown above and copy/pasted the code and it works. The ! and ? are for optionals and to unwrap optionals - we are not using them in this case, and the child.value is AnyObject and needs to be downcast to a String using as!

Comment: Okay! Thank you so much! I will recheck firebase to make sure everything is structured properly.